# Overriding TextField label size in Android Jetpack Compose (without breaking scale animation)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I need to override label size in `TextField` in order to set different sizes for mobile and tablet. My first approach would be directly overriding font size:

```
TextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    label = {
        Text(
            text = label,
            fontSize = 20.sp
        )
    },
    ...
)
```

which actually works. The problem is that this size is 'statically' affecting to both states in the `TextField`, when it's empty and when I'm editing, which by default rescales as illustrated in the screenshots.-

[image]
[image]

**Any known way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation

`label - the optional label to be displayed inside the text field container. The default text style for internal Text is Typography.caption when the text field is in focus and Typography.subtitle1 when the text field is not in focus`

You have to create wrapper for BasicTextField to achieve changing font size / style without breaking scale animation. So code would look  something like this

```
 BasicTextField(
            .................

            decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
                // this helps to not mess with label scale transition
                MaterialTheme(
                    typography = MaterialTheme.typography.copy(
                        subtitle1 = labelStyleUnfocused, // your custom style with different font size TextField is not in focus
                        caption = labelStyleFocused // your custom style with different font size TextField is in focus
                    )
                ) {
                    val label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = if (labelText != null) {
                        {
                            Text(
                                text = labelText
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                    // places leading icon, text field with label and placeholder, trailing icon
                    TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                        ..........

                        label = label,
                        
                        ..........
                        
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
```